# Create same Table Schema in mysql like Mongoose

Tags: mysql, node.js

we can make somthing like that in mongoose and with that we can easaliy make a unique comment subpage for each article or product:

### mongoose.schema({title:{type:string},subtitle:{type:string},comments:[{
comment-subject:{type:string},{comment-body:{type:string}]});

i use mysql in node.js and trying to make somthing like that in mysql but i don not know how can i create that.

[i wannt to make somthing like that in node with mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUkE1.jpg)